# error when trying to run a wicket application under eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, wicket

i am trying to build a web application using wicket. but whenever i try to run, i get the following error

```
 SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
 org.apache.wicket.util.lang.Args.notNull(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at
 org.apache.wicket.request.resource.ResourceReference.<init>(ResourceReference.java:73)
    at
 org.apache.wicket.request.resource.ResourceReference.<init>(ResourceReference.java:89)
    at
 org.apache.wicket.request.resource.PackageResourceReference.<init>(PackageResourceReference.java:69)
    at
 org.apache.wicket.extensions.ajax.markup.html.form.upload.UploadProgressBar.<clinit>(UploadProgressBar.java:110)
    at
 org.apache.wicket.extensions.ajax.markup.html.form.upload.UploadProgressBar$ComponentInitializer.init(UploadProgressBar.java:92)
    at org.apache.wicket.extensions.Initializer.init(Initializer.java:36)
    at
 org.apache.wicket.Application.callInitializers(Application.java:788)
    at
 org.apache.wicket.Application.initializeComponents(Application.java:625)
    at
 org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.init(WicketFilter.java:575)
    at
 org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.init(WicketServlet.java:194)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)   at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at
 org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at
 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)     at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Can anybody please explain the reason for the error?

Comment: How did you set Wicket up? Did you use the Maven Quickstart? Is that quickstart without modifications running? Are you using the embedded Jetty server, or your own setup?

Comment: Also, since you are using wicket-extensions: what versions are you using? Wicket version, wicket-stuff, wicket-extensions etc. The versions should match.

Comment: @Blacklight,thanks...I have set up wicket using Maven and yes the quickstart works well.i am using the embedded jetty server itself and ya i feel i am wrong in the versions.thank u.

Comment: Alright, I put this as an answer to complete your question, if you figured it you an accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Wicket-Extensions, make sure that the versions of all Wicket dependencies match. I.e. if some additional dependencies are not updated yet, you should downgrade your main Wicket version.

Comment: Is the dependency for wicket-velocity a must? when i include the wicket-velocity-jar,i get an error as java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/velocity/app/Velocity and if the jar is removed, i get an error as java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.parameter.PageParameters        any suggestions?

Comment: No, unless you use Apache Velocity, you don't need that jar at all. The `PageParameters` API has changed, e.g. in Wicket 1.5, so check your imports and class-definitions! I still smell version conflicts, maybe you are using code-examples for earlier versions of Wicket, and those APIs changed.